# How can I add a checkbox into a jQgrid header

Tags: jqgrid

Each jQgrid row has multiple checkboxes, so I cannot use (just) the multiselect.

This is how the column is setup...

> { name: 'ColName', label: '', width: 50,
>   editable: true, sortable: false, edittype: "checkbox", formatter:
>   'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled:false}, index:"my_checkbox",
>   editoptions: {value:"Yes":"No"} }

When I click the checkbox in the header, the header is redrawn without the check.  I can capture the event, but cannot display the check to the user.

So my question would be, how can I get a checkbox to operate normally inside a header label OR how can I implement multiple multiselects.

Comment: The formatter:'checkbox are introduced to display boolean value in the column cells (not in the column header) as a checkbox. How you want to use checkbox in the column header?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by preventing the jQgrid events from firing after the checkbox event.

I changed my checkbox to...

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkBox(event)" />
```

and added the following method...

```
function checkBox(e) {
  e = e||event;/* get IE event ( not passed ) */
  e.stopPropagation? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

Comment: By the way, you can actually accept your own answer, so others know that there is a solution if they have a similar problem.

Comment: ha, funny.  i actually didn't know that. i have accepted it now.

Comment: I am running to the same problem can you kindly elaborate your answer please and where i will call the function.

if i use above code and declare

<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkBox(event)" />

inside jqGrid colName it shows error in console

Uncaught ReferenceError: checkBox is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (S0018_UserMailReceptionSetting.php:1)

Comment: This was so long ago, I no longer have the source. Sorry I can't help further.